# Is there a way to label the "0"'s and "1"'s of my gender variable,

Tags: r, label, factors, levels

Is there a way to label the "0"'s and "1"'s of my gender variable,  as 'Female' and 'male' so that on plotting i get "gender=male" instead of gender=1. I would also be ok with Male and Female. I rarely work with R, so forgive my simple question.

I tried

```
gender2 = factor(gender2, levels = c("Female", "male")
```

but it gave me an error. it also made me uncomfortable that i couldn't specify the values for the ordering so make sure female is for coding 0 and male for coding 1.

Comment: You want `gender2 <- factor(gender2, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Female", "Male"))`

Comment: `data.frame(x = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)) |> mutate(x = factor(x, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Female", "Male")))`

Comment: A follow up Q- could we possibly remove the "variable= " part of the label in plot to make it cleaner?

Comment: Follow-ups are better posted as a new question, and please [include all required data and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (as plain text) so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, please post as answer! If you're using `ggplot2` it sounds like you *might* be using something like `facet_wrap(..., labeller = label_both)`.  If so, just drop the `labeller` argument

Answer (score 0):

The `levels` argument of factor should be the values in your existing variable.  The `labels` argument is where you identify the words that should correspond with the existing values (in the same order).  For example:

```r
gender2 <- factor(gender2, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("Female", "Male"))
```

The above would attach "Female" to the value 0 and "Male" to the value 1.

Comment: wanted to ask here, as i dont think this small query requires a new post- but does assignment "=" vs "<-" matter in making factor var? i get different results (yours works, while = nulls everything- table(variable) shows 0)

Comment: @SakshiTewari If you change the `<-` to `=`, it shouldn't matter.  So, `gender2 = factor(gender2, ...)` should work.  If you did it with `<-` first and then tried again with `=`, without reverting `gender2` back to its original values, you would get the result you describe.